# Prove by induction that $1^3 + \dots + n^3 = (1 + \dots + n)^2$

Tags: summation, induction

I'm suppose to prove by induction:
$1^3 + \dots + n^3 = (1 + \dots + n)^2$

This is my attempt; I'm stuck on the problem of factoring dots.

[image: attempt]

Comment: yeah, but my friend said that this could be written as a geometric sequence so i wrote that beside the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your attempt looks OK as far as it goes (except for a missing superscript $2$ at one point, but that's not causing any further errors).

To prove that something is equal to $1^3+2^3+3^3+4^3+\cdots+n^3$, one must show that at each step the amount that gets added is the next cube.

So how much has to be added to $(1+2+\cdots+n)^2$ to get $(1+2+\cdots+n+[n+1])^2$?  We need to show that that is the next cube, $(n+1)^3$.  The amount that gets added is
$$
\begin{align}
& \phantom{={}} (1+2+\cdots+n+[n+1])^2 - (1+2+\cdots+n)^2 \\[6pt]
& = (A + [n+1])^2 - (A)^2 \\[6pt]
& = A^2 + 2A[n+1]+[n+1]^2 - A^2 \\[6pt]
& = 2A[n+1] + [n+1]^2.
\end{align}
$$
Now here it helps to know that
$$
A = 1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots+n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}.
$$
Thus the difference above is
$$
2A[n+1]+[n+1]^2 = n(n+1)[n+1]+[n+1]^2
$$
and this simplifies to
$$
n^3+3n^2+3n+1
$$
and finally to
$$
(n+1)^3.
$$
Next, there's the problem of organizing that into a presentable proof by induction.

Comment: Great approach. Wouldn't it be even more elegant also to factor out $(n+1)$ in the expression $n(n+1)[n+1]+[n+1]^2=n(n+1)^2+(n+1)^2$?

Comment: Is A just the set of counting numbers?

Comment: $A$ is the number $1+2+3+\cdots+n$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @String : Perhaps.

Comment: I think I'm missing some point. I don't understand why look for an amount that can be added to $(1+2+\cdots+n)^2$ to get $(1+2+\cdots+n+[n+1])^2$?

Comment: @user96110: If $1^3+...+n^3=(1+...+n)^2$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$ then they should increase by the same when move from the case $n$ to $n+1$. It is clear that the left hand side is increased by $(n+1)^3$, so Michael Hardy researches what happens to the right hand side.

Comment: @String : Because the whole point is to show that what gets added is $(n+1)^3$.  If you show that something is initially equal to $1^3$, and then what's added at the next step is $2^3$, and what's added at the next step is $3^3$, and what's added at the next step is $4^3$, etc., then you've proved that it's equal to $1^3+2^3+3^3+\cdots+n^3$ at the $n$th step.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: BTW I think you made a typo in the second last calculation. You must have $3n$ not $2n$ to *complete the cube*, right?

Comment: $n^3+3n^2+2n+1$ should be $n^3+3n^2+3n+1$

Comment: @Chris Typo fixed; thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:
$$
(n+1)^3 =(n+1)(n+1+n(n+1))=(n+1)(n+1+2(1+2+\dots+n))\\
$$
Then 
$$
(1 + \dots + n)^2+(n+1)^3=(n+1)^2+2(n+1)(1+2+\dots+n)+(1+2+\dots+n)^2\\
=(1+2+\dots+n+(n+1))^2
$$